# Must explicit function type arguments include all generic types in signature?

Tags: generics, f#

The following code has signature `'c -> 'c`:

```
let f (x: 'c) = x
```

However, the following code has signature `obj -> obj`:

```
let f<'a> (x: 'c) = x
```

Adding the `'c` type parameter fixes the signature, reverting it to `'c -> 'c`:

```
let f<'a, 'c> (x: 'c) = x
```

Is it possible to explicitly declare only some of the signatures? I basically want something along the lines of

```
let f<'a> (x: MyType<'c>) =
  let foo = doSomethingBasedOn typeof<'a>
  processXWithoutCaringAboutTypeC x foo
```

It's kind of like a deserialization or unboxing, so I need explicit type arguments for `'a`, but I really don't care about the type of `'c` and would rather not have to explicitly supply it (or a wildcard type).

Comment: I guess the problem is that, in your last example, ``processXWithoutCaringAboutTypeC`` will need to know about the type ``'c``, expecting it as a type argument (which will usually be inferred by the compiler). I doubt you can do any better than ``let f<'a> (x : MyType<_>) = ...``

Comment: Are you sure that doesn't constrain 'c to obj? (Not in front of computer right now)

Comment: What do you mean by 'that'?

Comment: `let f<'a> (x : MyType<_>) = ...`. Just tested now, it does indeed constrain `x` to `MyType<obj>`.

Comment: In that case, I suspect your function ``processXWithoutCaringAboutTypeC`` does not take a type parameter at all. Can you show its signature?

Comment: Sadly no; I have already refactored according to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55265710/2978652) (taking a `System.Type` parameter instead), and the code at the time was so experimental and messy I can't recall now how it looked.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To directly answer your question, there is no way to include only a subset of the generic parameters in an explicit generic parameter list (`<'a,'b,...>`), either when defining or when using a function.  But it's not clear from your description that this is actually important for your use case.

1. Just because you explicitly use generic type arguments on a function definition does not mean that you also need to do so when you call the function:

   ```
   let f<'a,'c> (x: 'c) = x
   f 1  # works fine with type inference
   ```
2. If the return type of `f` includes `'a` in some way in your second case, then type inference will probably also allow you to skip the explicit type parameters even on the definition of `f`.

However, if `'a` doesn't appear anywhere in the signature of `f` (as part of either an input or output) and it affects behavior in an important way, then it will need to be specified explicitly as a type argument when calling `f` because there's no way for F#'s type inference to determine what it should be, which will force you to specify the other type arguments too (though possibly as wildcards).

Comment: Thanks. Unfortunately for me, the case is indeed your point #2. `MyType<_>` contains members of type `System.Type`, and `'a` is used to compare against this type. The type parameter to `MyType<_>` is not relevant for that particular comparison. So I must specify `'a` explicitly when calling.

Comment: In that case instead of using a generic parameter `'a` you can just receive a parameter `ta` of type `System.Type`, and do the comparison that you need to do with it. If you pass `ta` as the first parameter then you can even use partial application.

Comment: Yes, I just started experimenting with that, in fact. :) Thanks!